# Regex select names in next lines after match (until...)

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regex-group, regex-lookarounds

I have a text file with different levels (scructured by tabs) and I need to select certain values out of it. Here is an example. I tried this for a very long time, but I can't find any solution.

```
        Connection
            Match
                Fridolin
                Marten
    Connection
            Inventory
                        Fill Up
            Fill Up
        Match
            Peter
            Marcus
        Storage
                Room 1
                Room 2
                Room 3
            Match
                Albert
                Jonas
                Hans
    List
    Match
        Peter
        Marcus
```

I want to select every name in the following lines after "Match" (which has the same amount of tabs in front of it) until the next level (different amount of tabs) starts. In this case I want to select the names that are listed after the word "Match". Until (for example) "Connection" pops up and the amount of tabs in front of it (level) changes. The Names that follow "Match" are always on the same level. I can't use multiline for this.

```
            Match
                Fridolin
                Marten
    Connection
```

```
(?<=Match[\r\n]+\t\t?\t?\t?\t?)([ a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜßé0-9\.-/\-])+
```

I have already this regex, which selects at least the first name that follows "Match". I don't know how to select the next names and stop if the level changes.

Comment: You want to fetch only the names or also `Connection`?

Comment: @GillesQuénot Only the names. Connection is meant to be the ending point.

Comment: Do you want to match only the names that preceded by `Match` and must ending with `Connection` ?
and what programming language you are using ?

Comment: @SaSkY Yes, only those preceded by Match. The "Connection" is variable and can be literally anything. I'm just using Regex inside Power Automate Desktop, no specific language. Thats why I can't use multiline.

Comment: @SevenTwo Is there a max number of the names after Match ?

Comment: @SaSkY No, it needs to be endless until the tabs in front of it (the level) changes in the following line (so the following line isn't a name anymore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Try this:

```
(?<=Match)\n(\s+)\w+(?:\n\1\w+)+
```

[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/7tzWyR/1)

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(?<=` | [look behind](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is: |
| `Match` | 'Match' |
| `)` | end of look-behind |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `\s+` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `\w+` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `(?:` | group, but do not capture (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)): |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |
| `\1` | what was matched by capture \1 |
| `\w+` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)+` | end of grouping |

Comment: Hey @Gilles Quénot this works great. There is just one little problem, as soon as there are more than 2 names that follows match, it stops selecting those. See third match for example, it misses "Hans". Any idea?

Comment: This works for the specific example, where there are only two names after each match and they are indented with the same number of spaces. However, if there are more names, or if the indentation is different, this regex will not match all the names. This would fit better:`(?<=Match\r?\n)(?:\t+[^\t\r\n]+\r?\n)+`

Comment: Hi @Kylar, your approach is similar to mine. Problem is, that this just selects EVERYTHING after match. I really only want to select the names after wherever match is used, until the tabs in front of it changes in the following line (so the following line isn't a name anymore).

Comment: @SevenTwo I see, in that case you can look for lines that start with the same number of tabs as the "Match" line, but stop matching as soon as a line is found with fewer tabs. `(?<=Match\r?\n)((?:\t+[^\t\r\n]+\r?\n)+(?!\t))` How is that?

Comment: @Kylar Thanks for you effort! Unfortunately, this does the same. Only thing it, that it starts at a later "Match"

Comment: @Gilles Quénot With a little bit of editing this worked. Thanks!

Comment: You don't really need the lookbehind, you could also match it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\bMatch\n((\s*).*\n(?:\2.*(?:\n|\Z))*)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/DBbxpo/2)

---

This will match `Match`, following newline and then any number of whitespaces as capturing group 1. Then use this capturing group to match other lines.

Comment: Hey @Andrej Kesely, thanks. But I can't use multiline as I wrote and I don't want to select any tabs or "Match" itself. I really only want to select the names.

Comment: If you are matching the rest of the line, you don't have to use the non greedy `.*?` you can just make it `.*` https://regex101.com/r/DBbxpo/1

Comment: Hi, @Thefourthbird. Do you have maybe a better solution for my problem? Although I wrote it worked, it doesn't seem to work the right way.

Comment: @SevenTwo You have 2 answers that solve the problem for the current question. If you have a different question, consider creating a new question.